# After I installed 14.04 desktop, launcher on left side is missing

Tags: launcher

After I installed the ubuntu 14.04 desktop, the unity launcher on left side is not appearing. I have confirmed that unity is installed.

[image]

Comment: The root account and NIS accout can not see launcher, but there is a local common account, and it can see the launcher normally.

Comment: After I install gnome by "apt-get install gnome" I can login to see Ubuntu desktop now. But I can not see it in VNC viewer yet. Need more investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether unity-panel-service is running? The path is /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service. The package that provides this is unity-services. Please check whether the package is installed.

Comment: The file /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service exists and I can check it's running by ps aux|grep unity